# ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.translationY rendering with differents screen sizes

Tags: android, android-animation

May be the answer is very simple but I'm new to Android Animations. I have the following code working ok in my Nexus 5 device(with 4.95-inch 1080x1920 display):

```
ViewCompat.animate(imageView)
                .translationY(-400)
                .alpha(1)
                .setStartDelay(200)
                .setDuration(800).setInterpolator(
                new DecelerateInterpolator(1.2f)).start();
```

The animation  translate the image 400 points (pixels?) up, and ends in the place I want it to be.
The problem is when my app is running on the emulators Nexus(800x1280) 7 and Nexus 10(2560x1600), in these two cases the size of the movement in the Y axis is different between themselves and differents too with respect to the phone,e.g, I ended up tranlating 400 points in 3 devices, but the movement is different in the three cases. My question is how can I make this movement equal for all screen sizes(with just a number) and thus not having to use a variable in the translationY(var) method? or do I have to use a variable taking into account the 3 possible cases?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use dimen folder to set the dimension , there is four dimen folder you have to specify the four diffrent value according to your need

Comment: Ok, I will try it. but i don't understand why I can't set that value in dp, i mean in the translationY() method.

Comment: for the diffrent device you can't hardcode the value

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your solutions works 100%